# Convert SQLCE database to SQL Server 2008 with WebMatrix when database size > 256Mb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have a website with a SQLCE database which has grown to around 500Mb.  There were errors with the website when the database exceeded 256Mb, which were circumvented by applying 'Max Database Size = 1024' to the connection string in web.config.  Fine for now.

However, I'd like a more robust database going forward, so I want to convert to SQL Server 2008 Express.  Normally this is possible in WebMatrix (and I think in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express too) but on this occasion neither WebMatrix nor Visual Web Developer are able to access the database to publish it because they're both getting file size errors, which must be related to the way those programmes access the SQLCE database.

Does anyone know how to either increase Web Matrix or Web Developer Express' permitted SQLCE database size, or is there another tool which 100% robustly converts larger SQLCE databases to full MSSQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible in WebMatrix, not VS Web Dev Express. Suggest you try my Exportsqlce command line utility, it has been tested with large(ish) database files. And if it does not work, I will make it! http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks Erik - this will keep keys intact etc?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's possible to open a SQLCE4 database in SQL Server Management Studio 2008Rs Express, so scuppered here too :(

Comment: My Tool will create a script, keeping everything intact, that you can run againsta an empty SQL Server database.